# Vue3 onMounted props not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How do I get access to my properties with vue3, `onMounted` function?

I'm using the `setup script` tag:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed, defineEmits, defineComponent } from "vue";

defineComponent({
  name: "DatePicker",
});

interface Props {
  configuration: object;
}

withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  configuration: () => ({}),
});

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(configuration);
});
</script>
```

`configuration` is not defined.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  configuration: () => ({}),
});

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(props.configuration);
});
```